# Is it possible to search within a MongoDB field with type of Date or Int?

Tags: mongodb

I have a search field within my application that I want users to enter a search term into and it searches across various fields in each Mongo document. Naturally, I can search data within the fields that are of type `String` (currently using a regular expression), but how do I do this for those with type `Date` or type `Int` that?

Note: when I say search within the field, I mean if a user types '16' into the search field, it will return dates that contain '16', e.g. 01/01/2016 or 16/03/2014. Same principle for integers.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way I think is you can use $where
value to search val = "16"

```
db.foo.find({$where : "function(){ if(this.dateField.toString().indexOf(val)>= 0 || (""+this.intField).indexOf(val)>=0){return true;}}"})
```

What basically you can try is convert the field value into string and then search it in there. Downside is $where doesn't uses index, it basically scans the collection, You cannot use other operators when you are using $where.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

You can tell your find() to look into only fields which are of specific data types.

```
$type comes handy.
```

check out the following link for examples and usage.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

an example  would be

```
db.addressBook.find({"field": "search-value"}, { "field" : { $type : "double" } } )
```

will return documents where search-value has a match as well as if the field is of type double.

Comment: How do you combine this method with searching in fields of type String?

Comment: Won't the query above just return documents where the field is of type "double"? If so, this doesn't address the original question.

Answer (score -1):

since i have an image hence posting it as another answer rather than a comment.

[image]

now if you notice, documents with ID 2 and ID 6 are exactly the same. Only difference is the data type for the zipcode field.

i ran my query with $and as you can see and it bring backs only the matching record. if i get rid of the $and and the $type condition it will bring back both the records.

i hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: The question doesn't ask to limit the results returned based on the data type. It is asking to search for a number within a Date or Int32 field.

Comment: ok i misunderstood it completely will try to find a workable solution.